# Set table using "setFixedPosition" on specified page in a reopened PDF document

Tags: itext, itext7

This question is the follow up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53412506/1729265) on stackoverflow.

I open an existing PDF with this code snippet:

```
reader = New PdfReader(filenameSource)
writer = New PdfWriter(destFile)
pdf = New PdfDocument(reader, writer)
doc = New Document(pdf, pdf.GetDefaultPageSize, False)
```

I can add a paragraph now via `doc.add(new Paragraph(...))`
But when I try to place a table with `table.setFixedPosition(...)`, the table doesn´t show on the page.

Has anybody any hint for me?

Thanks and best regards

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your information I wrote this piece of code:

```c#
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("LoremIpsum.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("LoremIpsum-with-positioned-table.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdf, pdf.GetDefaultPageSize(), false);

Table table = new Table(new float[] { 200 });
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("test")).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.CYAN));
table.SetFixedPosition(1, 100, 100, 200);
doc.Add(table);

doc.Close();
```

This didn't reproduce your issue

> when I try to place a table with table.setFixedPosition(...), the table doesn´t show on the page.

because the result looks like this:

[image: screen shot]

The table clearly shows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I appreciate this very much!
I will go back into my own code and look for the error - that must be in there anywhere.

I will come back here to tell my results or any new questions....

Comment: I don´t know what my error was - but I deleted the whole code and wrote it again, and I was very accurate.... and now it works. Sorry for bothering you and thank you for your help!